java.sql.SQLException: while preparing SQL
I have this method in java:
    @Retry
    @SqlQuery("""
            WITH IdsGrouped AS (
                SELECT /* comment */
                    record_key,
                    max(gen_datetime) as max_dt
                FROM "ad".iceberg_data.<sourceSchema.schema>_<sourceSchema.tablePrefix>
                WHERE record_key IN (<ids>)
                GROUP BY record_key
            )
            SELECT *
            FROM "ad".iceberg_data.<sourceSchema.schema>_<sourceSchema.tablePrefix>
            WHERE (record_key, gen_datetime) IN (SELECT * FROM IdsGrouped)
            """)
    @UseStringTemplateEngine
    @RegisterRowMapper(MapMapper.class)
    List<Map<String, Object>> findDataById(@Define("sourceSchema") SourceSchema sourceSchema,
                                     @DefineCollection(value = "ids") Collection<String> ids);

I'm passing relevant arguments to the method, but getting this error:
org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException: java.sql.SQLException: while preparing SQL:
    WITH IdsGrouped AS (
        SELECT /* comment */ 
        record_key,
        max(gen_datetime) as max_dt 
        FROM "ad".iceberg_data.bl_merged WHERE record_key IN ('69823926','70674377','101113') 
        GROUP BY record_key
        ) 
     SELECT * 
     FROM "ad".iceberg_data.bl_merged 
     WHERE (record_key, gen_datetime) IN (SELECT * FROM IdsGrouped)

This is querying a data source in dremio and the query works in the UI.
Trace:
at com.btg.fit.nex.pln.common.persistence.decorator.RetryDecorator.lambda$decorateHandler$1(RetryDecorator.java:35)
at net.jodah.failsafe.Functions.lambda$get$0(Functions.java:48)
at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:62)
at net.jodah.failsafe.Execution.executeSync(Execution.java:129)
at net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.call(FailsafeExecutor.java:376)
at net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.get(FailsafeExecutor.java:67)
at com.btg.fit.nex.pln.common.persistence.decorator.RetryDecorator.lambda$decorateHandler$2(RetryDecorator.java:31)
at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.internal.SqlObjectInitData$1.lambda$invoke$0(SqlObjectInitData.java:132)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.internal.Invocations.invokeWith(Invocations.java:44)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.internal.Invocations.invokeWith(Invocations.java:26)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.LazyHandleSupplier.lambda$invokeInContext$1(LazyHandleSupplier.java:82)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.internal.Invocations.invokeWith(Invocations.java:44)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.internal.Invocations.invokeWith(Invocations.java:26)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.LazyHandleSupplier.invokeInContext(LazyHandleSupplier.java:81)
at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.internal.SqlObjectInitData$1.call(SqlObjectInitData.java:138)
at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.internal.SqlObjectInitData$1.invoke(SqlObjectInitData.java:132)
at org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.SqlObjectFactory.lambda$attach$2(SqlObjectFactory.java:108)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.internal.OnDemandExtensions.lambda$invoke$5(OnDemandExtensions.java:98)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.internal.exceptions.Unchecked.lambda$function$4(Unchecked.java:76)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.internal.OnDemandExtensions.invoke(OnDemandExtensions.java:98)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.internal.OnDemandExtensions.lambda$createProxy$2(OnDemandExtensions.java:82)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi.callWithExtension(Jdbi.java:491)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi.withExtension(Jdbi.java:478)
at org.jdbi.v3.core.internal.OnDemandExtensions.lambda$createProxy$3(OnDemandExtensions.java:82)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy67.findDataById(Unknown Source)
at com.btg.fit.nex.pln.logistics.precombination.Fetcher.findDataById(Fetcher.java:68)

retry decorator:
@SqlMethodDecoratingAnnotation(RetryDecorator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Retry {
    int value() default 3;
}


I don't think I see an issue with the query. What could be causing this?

Would you mind sending the message of the exception? I am also a little bit suprised by the table name with two dots. What is the "ad" part?

updated the original post

thanks for the update. I see there is an java.sql.SQLException, these usually come from the DB. Can you tap the message in it?
Can you run the query interactively on psql or dbeaver or anything?

On a side note you could use a single level withou any joins and using a window function MAX(gen_datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY record_key)


WHERE (record_key, gen_datetime) IN (SELECT * FROM IdsGrouped)

Where/IN clause looks incorrect to me, IN works only for list. in your case its tuple?
You can you try with below syntax:
    WITH IdsGrouped AS (
    SELECT /* comment */ 
        record_key,
        MAX(gen_datetime) AS max_dt 
    FROM "ad".iceberg_data.bl_merged 
    WHERE record_key IN ('69823926', '70674377', '101113') 
    GROUP BY record_key
)
SELECT output.* 
FROM "ad".iceberg_data.bl_merged output
INNER JOIN IdsGrouped ig ON output.record_key = ig.record_key AND output.gen_datetime = ig.max_dt

